# Sagemaker script processor

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

> ```
> script_processor = ScriptProcessor(
>     base_job_name=job_name,
>     image_uri=processing_repository_uri,
>     role=role,
>     command=["python3"],
>     instance_count=instance_count,
>     instance_type=instance_type,
>     max_runtime_in_seconds=MAX_RUN_TIM)
> ```

```
script_processor.run(
    code="src/extract_data.py",
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(source=path, destination=destination),
    ])
```

Is there a possibility to specify `source_dir` when using ScriptProcessor. I tried to figure it out but I could not find anything. Is it designed to run independent scripts? if it is the case what are the alternative for doing it with sagemaker.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify `source_dir` when using SageMaker Processors. Processing jobs are designed to run independent scripts.

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own